# NServiceBus Subscriber failing on server

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

I have a rather simple Pub/sub setup which works fine on our developer machines but when I deploy to our test serveres it throws this error for all messages:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.HandleTransportMessage(IBuilder childBuilder, TransportMessage msg) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1328
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender, TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\unicast\NServiceBus.Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line 1247
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional.TransactionalTransport.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage msg) in c:\BuildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\impl\unicast\transport\NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transactional\TransactionalTransport.cs:line 480
```

We allready have other SendOnly, Distributors and workers running on the same servers, so msmq etc. should be installed corretly. **This is the first time however we are using Pub/Sub on these servers.**

If i use the exact same binaries and config on a developer machine it runs smoothly, but not on the servers which are 2008R2, Powershell V3.

We are using a fluent configuration for the subscriber:

```
    return NServiceBus.Configure.With()
        .DefineEndpointName(queuePrefix)
        .Log4Net(_serviceBusLog.Build())
        .StructureMapBuilder()
        .JsonSerializer()
        .License(ConfigTable.GetConfigString(ConfigTableKeys.NServiceBus, "License"))
        .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .RunTimeoutManagerWithInMemoryPersistence()
        .EnablePerformanceCounters()
        .UnicastBus()
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => NServiceBus.Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

We also have our own UnicastBus config which scans for message handlers (they're message types) and then  automatically creates the endpoint mappings. This was my first concern so I disabled it and used the app.config way of setting up endpoints, but the error still occurs.

Note the error occours for every single message.
Note we are running version 3.3.5 of NSB.

Im still travering the server settings as I believe there must be some difference that makes it tick but i have not found it yet.

Anyone has any recommendations as for what to look for?

Kind regards

Comment: This seemed to be a double post (see http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/19858), answered in yahoo mailing list

Comment: But its not solved yet :). Im just trying reach the broadest audience possible by posting in 2 forums as the problem is rather serious :).

Comment: Is it the Publisher that is failing, or the Subscriber?

Comment: It is the subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have found the error.

After testing a raw simple console Pub/Sub on the server I added a try catch in the handler and caught... My own exception....

Im embrassed.

But it appears that the exception is not forwarded correctly to the log in NSB and i was therefore completely thrown of from the real problem.

I do not know if this is something that is fixed in later versions of NSB, but i hope so.
Until then Im using my own try catch logic to add a custom log entry.

Kind regards.